# How can I get more then 30 feed items?

Tags: support, tags, feed

I subscribed the [feed for the tag 'ruby'](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=ruby&sort=newest).

This works fine, if I refresh in short time intervals. If there is a bigger time interval (approx 4-5 hours) there are more then 30 questions, but the feed contains only 30 new questions.

Is there a possibility to get more? I would like read all new questions.

Or in other words: The feed has a limit of 30 items - is there a way to increase it?

Comment: Perhaps you could use an RSS client that stores all the new entries?

Comment: Would be a possibility. I had a similar problem in the past on another website. I added a _&items=100_ in the feed-url and I got the result. I just hope there is a similar option at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [Stack2RSS](http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/), you can use the following feed URL to accomplish this:

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/questions?tagged=ruby&body=true&pagesize=100

Note the inclusion of the `pagesize=100` parameter, which is the maximum number of items that can be retrieved from the API.

Comment: How did you get a .stackexchange.com sub-domain? :D

Comment: @Benny: It's not mine - Stack Exchange offered to install and run Stack2RSS on their server. It's an open-source application.

Comment: Great! There is an additional advantage: I can see, if there are already answers.