# How could I get more than 30 RSS entries in StackOverflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, feed

I've seen this answer:
[How can I get more then 30 feed items?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126078/how-can-i-get-more-then-30-feed-items)

and these useful ones:

[Any way to get an RSS feed of 'newest' tagged questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10140/any-way-to-get-an-rss-feed-of-newest-tagged-questions/25389#25389)

[What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on Stack Exchange and its sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/what-other-hidden-or-inobvious-rss-feeds-are-available-on-stackexchange-and-stac)

but I don't really see a good way to query more than the default 30 results from StackOverflow. The XML data obtained from Stack2RSS doesn't contain useful information, such as tags, author, views count and votes count, so it's not a good solution for me.

I'd really would like to get the default feed data obtained from https://stackoverflow.com/feeds but having the ability to specify how many results to retrieve.

Is that possible?

Comment: Nope. The RSS feeds are not that flexible. Use the API and code your own instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS is a relatively simple format that isn't really designed for what you seem to want to do. It basically only specifies title, date, URL and content (excerpt) with some extensions for podcasts that aren't really relevant here.

Since you want attributes not exposed in the RSS feed, such as tags, view count, votes, etc., you should build your own application against the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/). Fortunately the API is simple enough that even I can use it!